# Synapse TTcpBlockSocket

Tags: multithreading, delphi, freepascal

I have used Indy most of the time in past but decided to modify the existing project and use synapse instead of Indy. Although, i do have a small question to ask i.e. we all know whenever we create the socket object in Indy it runs on it's own thread, it does all IO operations on the thread it created and doesn't get free or shut down till the object is freed i think.

So pretty much i want to mimic this on synapse.

**tl;dr:**

How to create a `Ttcpblocksocket` object in such a way that it runs all its IO operations on a thread which doesn't get terminated until the object is free ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both libraries do not create a thread to manage client-side socket operations. This allows to create and use them on the application main thread - for example in a VCL event handler which runs a HTTP request - or to move them to a thread (for example to wait in the background for messages sent from the server to the client).

There is the TIdTCPServer component in Indy which creates threads to process incoming data concurrently, but there is no TCP multi-threaded server component in the Synapse library AFAIK.

**tl;dr**

There is no significant difference between the Indy and Synapse TCP *client* components regarding their usage with threads.

Comment: from what i have seen in case of synapse if you connect to a host on the main thread it will block the thread unless i run it on a new thread unlike Indy where it actually doesn't freezes the thread so i assumed it creates its own thread.

Comment: @deeznutz both Synapse and Indy TCP clients are blocking, the Connect method will return when a timeout occurs or the connection is established

Comment: @deeznutz in Indy, `Connect()` *does not* run in a separate thread, it *does* block the calling thread. If that is the main UI thread, the UI will be frozen, unless you use the `TIdAntiFreeze` component to allow messages to continue being processed while the main message loop is blocked.

Comment: @RemyLebeau and mjn Thanks for correcting me either way i have to make an application where i call the [code]Connect()[/code] in a new thread and then perform some io operations and then start two new threads one for writing and one for reading and keeping the thread "connect" thread paused while both reading and writing threads aren't terminated also is there any examples you guys aware of where this kind of threading model is utilized ?

Comment: @deeznutz why do you need three separate threads? Why can't you use just one thread for everything? One thread that runs a loop, where each iteration calls `Connect()`, performs its read/write IO, and then disconnects. Then the next iteration will connect again, do its IO, and disconnect. And so on until terminated.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I will be basically connecting to the server where the data has to be exchanged in real time and the IO operations won't be disrupted till the time either server restarts or i shut off my application. Adding to that, I won't be knowing what kind of and how much data i would be receiving (i have to decode the messages based on headers).

Comment: @deeznutz you still do not need multiple threads for that. A single thread can handle that model.

Comment: @RemyLebeau could you please illustrate it with the help of an example thanks ?

Comment: @deeznutz: examples are available if you search around, especially in the Indy and Embarcadero forums. Asking for the code is off-topic here. Try writing some code yourself first, and then post a new question here if you run into any trouble with it.